# Wait until jquery ajax request is done and return value

Tags: jquery, ajax, return-value, file-exists

I want to wait until ajax call complete and return the value.

```
function isFileExists(url) {
    var res = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function () {
            res = true;
        },
        error: function () {
            res = error;
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
    return res; //It is always return false
}
```

I want to return the value "true/error"

Please help me.

Comment: consider using jquery tag instead of javascript next time, its gonna make it more specific and save people time. Thank You

Answer (score 10):

You can't do this.  That's not how ajax works.  You can't depend on the ajax request completing at any given time ... or *ever* completing.  Any work you need to do that is based on the ajax request ***must*** be done in the ajax callbacks.

jQuery makes it easy to bind callbacks (because `jqXHR` returned by jQuery's ajax methods implements [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)):

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({/* snip */});

/* millions of lines of code */

jqXHR.done(function () {
    console.log('true');
}).fail(function () {
    console.log('false');
});
```

---

P.S. you can do what you want to do if you set `async` to `false`, but that locks up the browser while the request runs.  Don't do it.  Then you just have jax.

**EDIT**: You can't combine `crossDomain: true` and `async: false`.  Cross Domain must be asynchronous.

Comment: you mean `async` to `false`

Comment: @ExplosionPills : I am calling isFileExists(url) from another function. How can I call jqXHR

Comment: @Sagar in `isFileExists` do `return $.ajax(...)`.  Then you can use it like `isFileExists(url).done(function () {`

Comment: @ExplosionPills isFileExists(url).done(function () { //here I want result value how can I get it });

Comment: @Sagar is the result value sent from the server?  Then just do `.done(function (resultValue) {`

Comment: @ExplosionPills when I try isFileExists(url).done(function (returnval) { alert(returnval+"===saa"); }); it is saying isFileExists(url).done() not a funtion

Comment: @Sagar can you post your `isFileExists` function on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @Sagar the fiddle won't work because the url is not defined.  Or are you saying it's not working in your production code.  *Please* take some initiative and try to debug the issue on your own; it's not that complicated

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work for you:

```
function isFileExists(url, init) {
    var res = null;
    var _init = init || false;

    if (!_init) {
        _init = true;
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: url,
             crossDomain: true,
             dataType: "script",
             success: function () {
                 res = true;
             },
             error: function () {
                 res = 'error';
             },
             complete: function () {

             }
        });
    }

    if (res==null) {
        setTimeout(function(){ isFileExists(url, _init); }, 100);
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

I tested it briefly, but not cross domain.

Comment: Yes it should be called until the ajax request has been resolved.

Try adding the 'timeout' setting to the ajax call, setting it to 1 minutes (maybe), as means to escape.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it worked for me.

```
 function getInvoiceID(url, invoiceId) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: { invoiceId: invoiceId },
            async: false,
        });
    }
    function isInvoiceIdExists(url, invoiceId) {
        $.when(getInvoiceID(url, invoiceId)).done(function (data) {
            if (!data) {

            }
        });
    }
```